# Google .Net Core page indexing

Tags: .net-core, indexing

I have a page on the internet that I want to index but google gives me the error "Alternate page containing a valid canonical page tag".
I used the way to add automatic canonical link generation: https://mattcrook.io/41304/canonical-urls-in-asp-net

I used three layouts depending on nobody/user/admin login and I think that's the problem.

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    Layout = "_Layout";

    if (Context.Session.GetString("loginType") == "user")
    {
        Layout = "_Layout_user";
    }
    if (Context.Session.GetString("loginType") == "admin")
    {
        Layout = "_Layout_Admin";
    }
}
```

View Shared:

- _Layout.cshtml
- _Layout_User.cshtml
- _Layout_Admin.cshtml

Everything works fine, the page changes according to who is currently logged in. The /Home/index page is different depending on who logs in because the menu in the navbar changes.